# Excel VBA + looping through sheets and if sheet name like pattern, rename the sheet

Tags: excel, loops, design-patterns, vba

I am trying to loop through sheets and if Sheet Name found patterns, I'd like to rename it.

Below is the code, however, it's not renaming it. However, the string pattern wasn't working. I also tried to do it via the exact name of the sheet, and still it doesn't goes into the Select Case statement

Note that, "* BE Consol" is indeed taking the spaces into consideration

```
For myforecastSheetsIndex = LBound(myforecastSheetsArray) To UBound(myforecastSheetsArray)

Select Case myforecastSheetsIndex
    Case Is = 1 

        For Each wsBEIndex In Workbooks(desWBtoModify).Worksheets

            Select Case wsBEIndex.Name
                Case wsBEIndex.Name Like "* BE Consol"
                    wsBEIndex.Name = BEInputAns & " BE Consol"
                Case wsBEIndex.Name Like "* BE"
                    wsBEIndex.Name = BEInputAns & " BE"
                Case wsBEIndex.Name Like "* BE input tab"
                    wsBEIndex.Name = BEInputAns & " BE input tab"
                Case wsBEIndex.Name Like "Forecast* BE*"
                    wsBEIndex.Name = "Forecast " & BEInputAns & " BE"
            End Select

        Next wsBEIndex

    Case 2 To sheetsNeeded  

        'More codes here
    Case Else   'Delete Sheets
        'Codes to delete sheets
End Select

Next myforecastSheetsIndex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Select Case statement is equivalent to the following If Then Else statement

```
        If wsBEIndex.Name = (wsBEIndex.Name Like "* BE Consol") Then
            wsBEIndex.Name = BEInputAns & " BE Consol"
        ElseIf wsBEIndex.Name = (wsBEIndex.Name Like "* BE") Then
            wsBEIndex.Name = BEInputAns & " BE"
        ElseIf wsBEIndex.Name = (wsBEIndex.Name Like "* BE input tab") Then
            wsBEIndex.Name = BEInputAns & " BE input tab"
        ElseIf wsBEIndex.Name = (wsBEIndex.Name Like "Forecast* BE*") Then
            wsBEIndex.Name = "Forecast " & BEInputAns & " BE"
        End If
```

If you look at that statement you can see that you are testing wsBEIndex.Name for equality with a True/False value, and a worksheet name is never (or not usually?) just a value of True or False.

The statement you are actually after is

```
        If wsBEIndex.Name Like "* BE Consol" Then
            wsBEIndex.Name = BEInputAns & " BE Consol"
        ElseIf wsBEIndex.Name Like "* BE" Then
            wsBEIndex.Name = BEInputAns & " BE"
        ElseIf wsBEIndex.Name Like "* BE input tab" Then
            wsBEIndex.Name = BEInputAns & " BE input tab"
        ElseIf wsBEIndex.Name Like "Forecast* BE*" Then
            wsBEIndex.Name = "Forecast " & BEInputAns & " BE"
        End If
```

or, as a Select Case statement

```
        Select Case True
            Case wsbeindex.Name Like "* BE Consol"
                wsbeindex.Name = BEInputAns & " BE Consol"
            Case wsbeindex.Name Like "* BE"
                wsbeindex.Name = BEInputAns & " BE"
            Case wsbeindex.Name Like "* BE input tab"
                wsbeindex.Name = BEInputAns & " BE input tab"
            Case wsbeindex.Name Like "Forecast* BE*"
                wsbeindex.Name = "Forecast " & BEInputAns & " BE"
        End Select
```

Comment: So are you suggesting that I should be using IF statement instead of Select statement?

Comment: I found the workaround so that you **can** use a Case statement - see latest edit

Comment: Thanks YowE3K.

Although I haven't tested the Select Case statement, but using the IF statement, I was able to get the result. I'm confident that the Select Cast statement that you've given will also work.

Reps up to you!

Comment: Although I prefer the Select Case statement in most circumstances, I find it to be non-intuitive when it is written as "Select Case True".  (I **know** it works, and I know **why** it works, but it still looks odd.)  So, personally, I would tend to use the If statement for this situation.

Comment: By the way, quick question...is there a way to add a condition?

For example, Case wsbeindex.Name Like "* BE"  and  Case wsbeindex.Name Like "Forecast* BE*", they are almost the same, except 1 has the word 'Forecast' and the other doesn't.

So is there a way let say on Case wsbeindex.Name Like "* BE"
to ensure that there's no string 'Forecast'?

Comment: Change the order of the two Case statements.  It will only process the first statement that evaluates to True so, if you check for "Forecast* BE*" first and it is false then, when you get to "* BE" and find it is true you will already know that it doesn't match "Forecast* BE".

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, by changing the order. But was curious if there's a way to add to a condition for a regular expression.

Thanks YowE3K for your help. Really appreciate it!